# Receiving transactions to a company bank account located in a different country

Tags: international, business, banking

Can a company based in a country A receive incoming transactions to a bank account that belongs to the company but is in a different country?

Comment: There is even a name for this common practice, which is called correspondent banking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondent_account

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Most, if not all, banks that have a presence in two or more countries can transfer funds between accounts.

See this article from [Money Supermarket](https://www.moneysupermarket.com/international-money-transfer/business-transfers/) on "Products to help your business transfer money to and from the UK" for example:

> Transfer money is cash you move from your UK bank account to another account overseas. This will typically incur various charges, but you can usually get more competitive deals by using a foreign exchange specialist instead of your regular bank or building society.

What the consequences of such a transfer may be, such as tax liabilities or breaches of accountancy or money laundering regulations etc, is fact-dependant.